# What does "for some time" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I'm reading a hard-to-read article and it has this sentence:

> GPT-formatted disks work closely with firmware interfaces that have been established for some time as a successor to BIOS.

So as the title, what does it mean? Could you explain with some similar examples for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interfaces are not new; they were established *some time* ago (an unspecified period). The length of time you understand it to mean depends on context. As this is computer technology, I would guess 'a few years'. If someone says they have been waiting for a bus or train *for some time*, they might mean 20-30 minutes.

Comment: Thank you! This is much easier to grasp for me!